# Create a heap that prioritizes based on occurance of competitor field

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

This is a mockup variable that i am using to test:

```
[
    { competitor: 1 },
    { competitor: 1 },
    { competitor: 1 },
    { competitor: 1 },
    { competitor: 2 },
    { competitor: 3 },
    { competitor: 4 },
    { competitor: 4 },
    { competitor: 4 },
    { competitor: 5 },
    { competitor: 6 },
    { competitor: 6 },
    { competitor: 7 },
    { competitor: 7 },
    { competitor: 7 },
    { competitor: 8 },
    { competitor: 9 },
    { competitor: 10 },
    { competitor: 11 },
    { competitor: 12 },
  ]
```

This is the code for grouping repeated items:

```
const splitRepeated = (array) => {
  let obj = array.reduce((res, curr) => {
    if (res[curr.competitor]) res[curr.competitor].push(curr);
    else Object.assign(res, { [curr.competitor]: [curr] });

    return res;
  }, {});
  return obj;
};
```

This is the result:

```
{
  '1': [
    { competitor: 1 },
    { competitor: 1 },
    { competitor: 1 },
    { competitor: 1 }
  ],
  '2': [ { competitor: 2 } ],
  '3': [ { competitor: 3 } ],
  '4': [ { competitor: 4 }, { competitor: 4 }, { competitor: 4 } ],
  '5': [ { competitor: 5 } ],
  '6': [ { competitor: 6 }, { competitor: 6 } ],
  '7': [ { competitor: 7 }, { competitor: 7 }, { competitor: 7 } ],
  '8': [ { competitor: 8 } ],
  '9': [ { competitor: 9 } ],
  '10': [ { competitor: 10 } ],
  '11': [ { competitor: 11 } ],
  '12': [ { competitor: 12 } ]
}
```

Now i need to distribute the repeated elements of this array evenly;

evenly example:

```
[{ competitor: 1 },{ competitor: 2 },{ competitor: 3 },{ competitor: 1 },{ competitor: 4 },{ competitor: 5 },{ competitor: 1 }]
```

this is my best try at all:

```
const spreadOrder3 = (array) => {
  let obj = splitRepeated(array);
  let objEntities = Object.entries(obj);
  console.log(obj);
  let newArray = objEntities.map((x) => x[1][0]).flat();
  let oldIndex = newArray.length;
  for (let e = 0; e < oldIndex; e++) {
    let each = Math.floor(oldIndex / objEntities[e][1].length);

    let counter = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < objEntities[e][1].length; i++) {
      console.log(objEntities[e][1][i]);
      console.log((counter + 1) * each);
      newArray.splice((counter + 1) * each, 0, objEntities[e][1][i]);
      // newArray[(counter + 1) * each] = objEntities[e][1][i];
      counter++;
    }
  }
  return newArray;
};
```

The results aren't good, i need help, i can never get repeated elements together thank you

Expected result:

Array length unique elements: 12

competitor: 1 // has 4 repeated then: 12/4 = 3, then insert competitor 1 every 3 elements

competitor: 4 // has 3 repeated then: 12/3 = 4, then insert competitor 4 every 4 elements

competitor: 6 // has 2 repeated then: 12/2 = 6, then insert competitor 6 every 6 elements

competitor: 7 // has 3 repeated then: 12/3 = 4, then insert competitor 7 every 4 elements

Result needs to be like this:

```
[{ competitor: 1 },{ competitor: 2},{ competitor: 3 },{ competitor: 1 }, { competitor: 4 },{ competitor: 5 },{ competitor: 1 }]
```

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: Can you also enunciate in precise words just what the resulting array should look like? There has to be an easily describable patterns. *distribute the repeated elements of this array evenly* is hard to interpret and may mean different things to different people.

Comment: I added some results, I hope I could make it easier to understand

Comment: Is this another way to describe what you are looking for?

```
create a heap that prioritizes based on occurance of competitor field
```

Comment: Yes @PaulNikonowicz your description suits best my problem

Comment: what is the expected result if you have ```1,1,1,2,2``` ?

Comment: I don't understand why the title now speaks of a heap.

Comment: The objects with competitor properties seem to add an unnecessary complexity layer to this question. Why not ask the question about a collection of just integers? And could you then add a few examples with boundary cases? Like when it is impossible to avoid that the same values will be put next to each other or when the distance between two the same values will have to vary or when multiple solutions exist, and which of those should get priority,...

Answer (score 1):

You could group the values and sort the grouped values by length of the same value.

Take an array of indices for the result array and disperse the values of the same group with the same distance

```
Math.floor((indices.length - 1) / (a.length - 1))
```

into the result array by using the indices array. Remove used indices from `indices` array and proceed until no more values are to ditribute.

```
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19  indices at start

1  1  1  1  2  3  4  4  4  5  6  6  7  7  7  8  9 10 11 12  values
1                 1                 1                 1     d = 6
   4                       4                       4
      7                       7                          7
         6                                      6
            2  3     5  8        9    10 11 12              solitary values
```

```js
const
    data = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
    indices = [...data.keys()],
    groups = data.reduce((r, v) => ((r[v] ??= []).push(v), r), {}),
    result = Object
        .values(groups)
        .sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length)
        .reduce((r, a) => {
            const d = a.length === 1 ? 1 : Math.floor((indices.length - 1) / (a.length - 1));
            a.forEach((v, i) => r[indices.splice(i * d - i, 1)[0]] = v);
            return r;
        }, []);

console.log(...result);
```